# Netbeans 8.2: How to stop embedded Tomcat in Spring.Boot project on osx?

Tags: java, spring, macos, tomcat, netbeans

I have a simple `spring.boot` application which is executed on embedded `Tomcat`. 
In `Netbeans 8.2` after I run it for a first time it's ok. But when I run it second time I see in log that default port 8080 is used.

If I go to the `services` tab, there is no `Tomcat`. You can see at the image at console that application is run at `Tomcat`

[image]

I found that if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> it works.

But is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see `Tomcat` in your `services` tab because it is not running `Tomcat` from NetBeans, but as you said - an embedded container. To the IDE this is just a regular application, it's just a coincidence that it starts `tomcat` inside it.
So you need to stop it as a regular CLI application.